# Unable to install apk in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to install an apk (downloaded from one site) in ICS emulator through adb shell but its giving following error:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

What could be the issue?

Comment: @AkashG: From command prompt only its giving this error..!!!

Comment: pls post what u r writing in cmd.

Comment: @AkashG: adb install E:\HelloApp.apk

Comment: this is not the correct way to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall the previous version of the app from the emulator first, then try again. You can do this by visiting System Settings > Applications > Manage Applications and selecting the app.

If the app still fails to install, then start the emulator with the Wipe user data option selected.

Comment: As I said, its downloaded apk. So to uninstall previous it should install first :)

Comment: seems its application issue itself. In device its working fine but not in emulator.

Answer (score 11):

Simply rm -r the data directory in question.  If you were installing and got this error, you'd simply run "rm -r /data/data/com.app.class" from an ADB shell.  If you want to try preserving the data, you could find the proper UID and then "chown -R UID:UID /data/data/com.app.class".

In Android, the part of the source code that handles installing apps is PackageManagerService.  Since the Android source is public, it's easy to see where Android will throw a INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED error.  If the following is true:   the package you are installing already has a data directory AND the permissions on that data directory are different than the UID assigned to this package, you'll get that error.

Comment: My android flash was corrupted and previously installed apps were not working, icon was shown on a desktop. Reinstall from Store gave "application not installed, error code -25". Used adb.exe Android SDK tool: c:> adb shell, $cd /data/data/com.app.class, $rm -r *, $cd .., $rmdir com.app.class

Answer (score -3):

Open command prompt and write below code in it:

```
adb devices
```

This will list down the number of devices attached or are active.Copy your apk in your System folder

```
adb -s DEVICE_NAME install YOUR_APK_NAME
```

through this you will be able to install your particular apk on the device by giving device name in above line.

Comment: is it working??have you successfully installed apk in android emulator??