# INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED error while installing application

Tags: android

```
[2013-04-06 14:48:32 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Android Launch!
[2013-04-06 14:48:32 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-06 14:48:32 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Performing com.mobidevelop.widget.Demo activity launch
[2013-04-06 14:48:32 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Automatic Target Mode: using device '015d188469381013'
[2013-04-06 14:48:32 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Uploading SplitPaneLayout-Demo.apk onto device '015d188469381013'
[2013-04-06 14:48:32 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Installing SplitPaneLayout-Demo.apk...


[2013-04-06 14:48:34 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED
[2013-04-06 14:48:34 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-04-06 14:48:34 - SplitPaneLayout-Demo] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 12):

Just delete "/data/data/your.package.name" on your device

Comment: This worked for me since I wasn't on an emulator but a physical device. Had uninstalled via the command line to get into this situation but I've done that dozens of times before, not sure why this one was any different.

Comment: Note: use `rm -rf /data/data/your.package.name` to delete all files and folders in it.

Comment: Works only on rooted phone.

Comment: I had this problem on a Nexus 5 and solved it by resetting the phone to factory settings. Fine for me as it was a test phone..

Comment: sory, im a noob, how do u delete those file?

Answer (score 5):

If your device is not rooted and restarting doesn't work, I guess changing your package name is a good option if you're just debugging. Worked for me !

Comment: Unreal, but it works for me) But I did not understand why this happen and renaming of package solve an issue. But what I should to do to away this error in the future when I will update an application on Google Play with OLD PACKAGE NAME?

Comment: This worked for me also, but I'd like to understand what is actually happening here and fix it properly. Simply uninstalling didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just manually Uninstall your application from `Setting->Application->Manage Application->Your Application` This was getting because some data or string was in used so the system can't able to delete it that's why getting this error.

If still getting this problem then close your emulator then start your emulator with wiping your data.

here is more detail regarding this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662787/760489

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444895/760489

Comment: I already uninstalled my application,but still I am getting errors

Comment: I have this problem on my phone, which is not rooted. The methods above does not work, because you need root access to delete in data/data And the app was successfully uninstalled with adb uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

If you were just testing your app like me, then I just renamed by app name from xyz to abc and then deploy it again on your mobile device (mine was nexus 7 tab) then all worked fine !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting Cached Data under `Settings -> Storage`, this will clear all cached App data at once, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have added android:sharedUserId in your manifest. Remove it if it is not required. That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your device and clean the project. It happens sometime when we uninstall the application and try to install it again without restarting device.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error while working with emulator. I just delete that emulator and made a new emulator and install the apk into new emulator and it worked. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you still have the old UID stored in the Selendroid app in your phone. Go to Application Manager and uninstall the app called "Selendroid" and retry again. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf /data/data/your.package.name works for me.

You need to be super user. For me, since I use CyanogenMod 11.0, nexus, "su" in console let me switch to super mode.

Answer (score 0):

I followed most steps here 
eventually changed the gradle version i was working with to

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc3'

And it worked

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I could fix this issue just by changing the ApplicationId. This process does not require root or factory reset and wiping data in /data folder.

1. right click on the root folder of your project.
2. Click "Open Module Setting".
3. Go to the Flavours tab.
4. Change the applicationID to whatever package name you want. Press OK.

Credits to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336400/4657700

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing worked for me was to create a new emulator.