# cannot install android app because uid changed

Tags: android, adb

I get this same installation failure [Android INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed) and tried deleting my package:

[image]

I'm not sure if it was deleted because I tried running my app from Android Studio on my physical device again and get the same error:

```
pkg:/data/local/tmp/com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20088001/1505341

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_UID\_CHANGED error while installing application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849239/install-failed-uid-changed-error-while-installing-application)

Comment: I changed the path to /data/data/com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer for the delete and the cmd line just hangs.  How do I ls to check for the directory without rooting my phone?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project, uninstalling the app manually or a factory reset if root is not possible?

Comment: I cleaned it, uninstalled it.  I suspect I'm not really deleting /data/local/tmp/com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer because executing that command in adb just immediately shows the command I just ran, same as if I put in a nonexistent dir like rm -rf dfkjadslj.

Comment: Is this on linux? If on windows I would recommend starting cmd.exe "as administrator". Otherwise maybe you should temporarily root your device for this case since you can unroot it after you are done with this problem. It is interesting that simply cleaning the project is not enough. http://androidforums.com/galaxy-y-all-things-root/541670-steps-how-root-unroot-features-rooting.html this should be sufficient if you use an external sdcard for relatively quick root/unroot.

Comment: Hi mass, thanks for your efforts.  I am an administrator when I run adb shell in windows cmd.  I am using a Moto G; I read that it cannot be unrooted but ill look into it some more.