# How to change package name in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have made an app and it is my very first app so when I started coding, I left the package name as com.example.stuff and now when I try to upload to the play store it wont let me due to the package name. I have tried refactor-> rename the package name and changed it in the AndroidManifst.xml then I tried to upload again. I am once again left with the same message time after time.

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Yes, but none of the answers there worked for me. Sometimes I think it's good to post a question a second time because people come with newer solutions. Or what is the normal practice here to ask people "Hey, I now in thread xyz the quetion was already askes. But the answers didn't help me. So may someone have a modern solution for this problem?"?

Comment: The problem with this issue is that, IMO, all of the answers given are partial solutions.  I have never seen an answer to this question that changes the package name everywhere.

Answer (score 76):

First click once on your package and then click setting icon on Android Studio.

Close/Unselect **Compact Empty Middle Packages**

Then, right click your package and rename it.

Thats all.

[image]

Comment: Also, this video explain how solve your problem [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNcrzOMugn8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNcrzOMugn8)

Comment: Btw dont forget rebuild your application after make your changes. **Build>Rebuild App**

Comment: Just want to add, that is need to go to build.gradle (of the module) and change ApplicationID to

Comment: This is the perfect, accurate, appropriate, standard, best, amazing and proper way. Dot.

Answer (score 54):

In projects that use the Gradle build system, what you want to change is the `applicationId` in the build.gradle file. The build system uses this value to override anything specified by hand in the manifest file when it does the manifest merge and build.

For example, your module's build.gradle file looks something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        // CHANGE THE APPLICATION ID BELOW
        applicationId "com.example.fred.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

`applicationId` is the name the build system uses for the property that eventually gets written to the `package` attribute of the `manifest` tag in the manifest file. It was renamed to prevent confusion with the Java package name (which you have also tried to modify), which has nothing to do with it.

Comment: by doing this the package name in did not change anywhere else (package and manifest)

Answer (score 28):

It can be done very easily in one step. 
You don't have to touch AndroidManifest.
Instead do the following:

1. right click on the root folder of your project.
2. Click "Open Module Setting".
3. Go to the Flavours tab.
4. Change the applicationID to whatever package name you want. Press OK.

Comment: Didn't work: Build APK did NOT observe new package name.

Comment: I "lied". While the computer path still has old package name, APK somehow has new package name. Sorry.

Comment: @DSlomer64 No worries.

Comment: That's the only solution which worked for me. Other approache were error-prone. Also the ones here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Comment: But that didn't change the package names throughout the project

Comment: @DeanBlakely It's the package name in gradle that's important. That's all that matters. The package name in gradle trumps other names.

Comment: Didn't work, the package names from the project files remain the same as original, no changes made.

Comment: * *cough* * 4 steps * *cough* *

Comment: Clear and Concise!! Very Thanks!!

Comment: I have followed ur instruction but its not working.

Comment: Worked for me, For all those said not changed, pls check in your gradle file , It will be changed there.

Comment: not working on android studio 3.0