# How can i create a new android studio project from existing code by changing of package name,app name using cmd prompt?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a android studio project, it is having a bulk of code,and number of packages

**Example:**

```
     com.oneproject.activites

     com.oneproject.services

     com.oneproject.broadcasts

     com.oneproject.adaptors 
     ......etc
```

I need to replace `com.oneproject` with `com.secondproject` by using `command prompt`.

Finally I need duplicate project with same code but different App Name,Package Name using command prompt.

Please guide me, Your help will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First click once on your package and then click setting icon on Android Studio.

Close/Unselect Compact Empty Middle Packages

Then, right click your package and rename it.

For More details : [How to change package name in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848046/how-to-change-package-name-in-android-studio?answertab=active#tab-top)