# Change the package name returned by mContext.getPackageName()

Tags: android, package, android-manifest

I have an app and I want to re-brand it. This is my code for sharing intent:

```
String shareBody = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + mContext.getPackageName();
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.enjoy_this_app));
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Please Choose"));
```

I have changed the package name EVERY WHERE in the project but still the mContext.getPackageName() returns the old name. 
(the package name is changed in manifest, gradle files, from project pane...)

I checked many posts here and I did everything recommended. Nothing worked.
Posts I checked:

[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)
[How to change package name of an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025369/how-to-change-package-name-of-an-android-application)
[How to change package name in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848046/how-to-change-package-name-in-android-studio)
[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

any idea what is going wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed package name in **build.gradle** and **manifest.XML** ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I Came with the similar issue even though I changed the package name Still it was giving me the old package...

To fix it Go to build.gradle file and replace **applicationId** manually to your new package name.
This was not affected by renaming the package