# Android Studio Rename Package with company name in it

Tags: android

I manage to found few of the answers here in stackoverflow. But not really suit well with my requirement which is to change from 'com.app' to 'com.company.app'

I tried this, but its only working if you want to change from com.a.app to com.b.app 
[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: what did you mean by not really suit well ?

Comment: *its only working if you want to change from com.a.app to com.b.app* Nope it is not!

Comment: Use the 2nd method - [3 methods to change package name in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848046/how-to-change-package-name-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on package name-> select Refractor->Move(F6) then select "Move package com.app to another package" then click yes then give new package name like com.mycompany and then click Do refractor.

This will completely refactor package name in entire project.

Now you can delete the old package.

Answer (score 0):

Example: `com.myapp` to `com.company.myapp`.

Go project folder, then find folder `app\src\main\com`.

Create new folder named `company`. Then move `myapp` folder to `company` folder you just created.

Go `app\build.gradle`, edit line

`applicationId "com.myapp"` to `applicationId "com.company.myapp"`

Go `app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`, edit all lines contain `com.myapp` to `com.company.myapp`.

Then go all java class inside your `src` and rename first line `packpage` with your new package.

This will be difficult but will work.

Answer (score 0):

Only need edit `build.gradle`, add the following code：

```
shell
defaultConfig{
        ...
    applicationId "com.company.app"
        ...
}
```

then, run it. You will find the package name is changed.